# Are the enclosed patents still valid?

Tags: patent-lifetime, us7774976

Are those patents still valid:

1. US7774976
2. US2009000183
3. US7774976

Also cited under:
DE10259651 (as we know, it expired due to no-payment, so how can above patents be applied for or granted?)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! I'm not sure I understand your question. Your #1 #3 look like duplicates Item #2 is an application for a patent, not a patent. The DE is a German patent document. Each country has its own system and their issued patents are separate things with separate lives.